# +URLWithString: returns nil

Tags: ios, excel, ms-word, nsdata, nsurl

Im using QLPreviewController to view word, excel,pdf etc. The problem is the file is in the server so I need to download it from a certain URL.

I'm using this code:

```
NSURL *dLurl = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",DLPathStr]];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:dLurl];
```

for downloading files, It works for the PDF file but in the word and excel files it doesn't work I'm not able to download anything.

Comment: Make sure you have correct URL for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by using this code it doesn't download anything because the URL is wrong because it contains spaces.

```
NSString *str = [DLPathStr stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL *dLurl = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",str]];
```